# Adding a manufacturing lead time to website Javascript to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, content-management-system

I'm using a CMS system that works alongside a backend that we must use. I'm trying to have it display a production lead time date such as www.customink.com. Current day +10 business days I'm using a HTML widget in this custom CMS, so I'm not sure if that is relevant. I'm struggling getting it to show up, and I really have no idea what I'm doing. I tried my best lol. Here's what I have thus far.

EDIT: Also, If I want it to only display M-F how do I go about that? I want it to read - Guaranteed by Fri, Oct 11.

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = newDate;

function addDays(theDate, days) {
return new Date(theDate.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000);
}
var newDate = addDays(new Date(), 10);;

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what CMS are you using? I have some experience with Wix and building in heavy javascript/Node into it. each of these CMS have developer docs which you can use to help guide you.

Comment: @sao It's called DecoNetwork, it's more of a hybrid CMS/ERP system

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = newDate;`

In this statement, what you are doing is trying to find the DOM element with id `p1` and then setting the value of `newDate` variable as its value. Therefore you should define an element with such id before your `script` block.

Then you are declaring and setting the value of the `newDate` after you have set the value for the above element. But you should do it before that.

See the fixed code below.
 (I have used a `<div>` element as the `p1` element. But you can use any other options such as `<span>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc. based on your requirement.)

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='p1'></div>

<script>
var newDate = addDays(new Date(), 10);
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = formatDate(newDate);

function addDays(theDate, days) {
  //return new Date(theDate.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000);
  return moment(theDate).add(days, 'd').toDate();
  
}

function formatDate(date) {
  return moment(date).format('[Guaranteed by] ddd, MMM DD');
}


</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<div>` is not a self closing tag

Comment: Ah! That makes perfect sense. This worked, thank you! As for formatting how the date displays, where do I adjust that? Clearly I have no idea how to code Javascript!

Comment: If for instance I wanted it to stay within M-F and is displayed as such - Guaranteed by Fri, Oct 11.

Comment: @HunterStrine Better to use a date manipulation library such as MomentJS (https://momentjs.com/) or DateJS (https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) for that. If you want to do it without any library, please see the below answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: @UdithGunaratna is it possible to use a library with a CMS that is not on our servers? I cannot access any servers etc.

Comment: Yes, for example, see below on how to add MomentJS to your web page.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browser/

Comment: I have updated my answer showing how to use MomentJS to format the date as you required. Please refer to the below for MomentJS formatting options.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: Also if you are going to use MomentJS, you can also use it to add days rather than doing it yourself. I have updated the `addDays` function with the use of moment. See this for date manipulation capabilities.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/